# Apache error log: zend_mm_heap corrupted, child process exited with status 1 -- Restarting

Tags: php, apache, session, runtime-error

I have seen some topics about 'zend_mm_heap' corrupted and 'child process exited with status nnnnn' but none of this topics lead to a solution. What does status 1 means in clear text, it is not clear what exactly happen.

**Symptoms**
This problem does not occur when the site is running without being logged in. Only when I logged in the problem sometimes happen when refreshing the page. Strange is that sometimes the html fails to load and sometimes resources like a CSS file or JS file. I also have seen that some resources take 6 seconds to 10 seconds to load. I think this is caused by restarting the server because of this error.

When above symptoms occur, the following (similar) info is written to the error.log file:

**Error in error.log file:**

```
zend_mm_heap corrupted
[Sun Feb 09 03:56:57 2014] [notice] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 1 -- Restarting.
[Sun Feb 09 03:56:57 2014] [notice] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win64) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 09 03:56:57 2014] [notice] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 14:13:48
[Sun Feb 09 03:56:57 2014] [notice] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3460
[Sun Feb 09 03:56:57 2014] [notice] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

**Configuration:**

- Intel I7 (Quadcore) chipset, 16GB RAM
- Running latest XAMMP (or Z-WAMP, in both the same problem - see for Z-WAMP also http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/) on Windows 7 64 bit
- Running APC  -

For example:
[image: Info in firefox-result of error - send headers]

Normal feedback (when problem does not occur):
[image: firefox ok]

**What I want to know**

- Does have somebody info about Apache status 1 exit?
- Am I able to debug this, how can I debug this?

Comment: Hm, first of all, run a memtest to see if you're memory is not broken. After that: start disabling PHP & Apache extensions until the problem no longer exist. Reinstall those extensions from scratch.

Comment: This forum is more for programming, and it looks like you have a question that is really about server software. I'd recommend posting this at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) since you need to debug the server instead of any programming. Also in `httpd.conf` (or `sites-enabled/whatever.conf`) set your [`LogLevel`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel) to `debug`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, see also my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with APC (I use version 1.3.1) that cause this error, corrupt memory for some reason. I believe it has something do with session data because the problems only occur when logged in. My PHP class uses only a session when it is required to be logged in to be able to view the page. I have also checked my code but there is nothing abnormal or incomplete.

When I turn off the Windows extension php_apc.dll in the php.ini file everthing is working fine. No memory corruption and no delays. Also tried other cache extensions like xCache, eAccelerator, memcache and loads normally.

So I qualify this as a bug.